# glDrawArrays not rendering to framebuffer (although glClear works fine)?

Tags: android, c++, unity-game-engine, opengl-es

I'm trying to render to a texture using OpenGL ES on an Android phone (using a native plugin/C++). I can set the color of the texture using `glClear`, and I can clear different sections to different colors using `glScissor` so I'm fairly sure the issue isn't the framebuffer setup/attachment. Probably there's an issue with the shaders or the vertex data, but I can't see what it is.

Here's the code I've reduced the problem down to:

```cpp
#include <GLES3/gl31.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2ext.h>
#include <GLES3/gl3ext.h>

const int32_t WIDTH = 512;
const int32_t HEIGHT = 512;

char vertex_code[] = R"(

#version 300 es

in vec3 VertexPosition;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0f);
}

)";

char fragment_code[] = R"(

#version 300 es
precision mediump float;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main() {

    FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

}

)";

GLuint compile_shader(char* shader_code, GLenum shader_type) {

    GLuint shader_id = glCreateShader(shader_type);
    glShaderSource(shader_id, 1, &shader_code, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(shader_id);

    // check shader compilation:
    GLint result = 0;
    glGetShaderiv(shader_id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result == GL_FALSE) {
        glDeleteShader(shader_id);
        return 0;
    }

    return shader_id;

}

GLuint create_shader_program(char* vertex_code, char* fragment_code) {

    GLuint vertex_id = compile_shader(vertex_code, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    GLuint fragment_id = compile_shader(fragment_code, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    GLuint shader_program_id = glCreateProgram();

    // attach shaders and link:
    glAttachShader(shader_program_id, vertex_id);
    glAttachShader(shader_program_id, fragment_id);
    glLinkProgram(shader_program_id);

    // check linking status:
    GLint result = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(shader_program_id, GL_LINK_STATUS, &result);
    if (result == GL_FALSE) {
        glDeleteProgram(shader_program_id);
        glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
        glDeleteShader(fragment_id);
        return 0;
    }

    // delete the shaders now that they're linked:
    glDetachShader(shader_program_id, vertex_id);
    glDetachShader(shader_program_id, fragment_id);
    glDeleteShader(vertex_id);
    glDeleteShader(fragment_id);

    return shader_program_id;

}

GLuint render_texture() {


    // *** create framebuffer and texture to render into
    GLuint framebuffer_id;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer_id);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer_id);

    GLuint target_texture_id;
    glGenTextures(1, &target_texture_id);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, target_texture_id);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, target_texture_id, 0);

    if(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        return 0;
    }

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    // *** create shader program
    GLuint shader_program_id = create_shader_program(vertex_code, fragment_code);

    // *** set up quad
    float quad[] = {
        // positions        
        -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
        -1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,

        -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
         1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
         1.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,

    };

    GLuint vertex_data_buffer, vertex_array;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertex_data_buffer);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);
    // load vertex data into VBO:
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_data_buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(quad), quad, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // position attribute
    GLint vertex_pos_location = glGetAttribLocation(shader_program_id, "VertexPosition");
    Log("vertex_pos_location %i", vertex_pos_location);
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_pos_location, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    // *** render
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer_id);
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(shader_program_id);
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

    glFinish();

    return target_texture_id;

}
```

When I use this texture elsewhere (within Unity, for what it's worth) I can see that the `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` call has worked fine, but I'm not seeing the pink colour I'd expect from the basic fragment shader. I've used `glGetError()` to check for errors after each GL call, and they all seem fine...

Any thoughts on what the issue could be?

Comment: The only thing I can see is: It has to be `glEnableVertexAttribArray(vertex_pos_location);` rather than `glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);`.